# matplotlib- Y and X axis are swapped

Tags: python, audio, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a spectrogram. I am using the `imshow` in matplotlib.

The problem is this, I am reading the data from a text file generated in C++ (it essentially creates a 2D vector and stores this into a text file) I then read in the text file and plot.

Below is the output of the plot I've generated (from C++ and imported into python):

[image]

Here is a plot of a spectrogram, actually in Python (using matplotlib):

[image]

As you can see, the x and y axis are swapped, which is giving me the wrong shape for the actual spectrogram.

Why could this be? For example, could I be reading in the data wrong in the first place and this has happened? Or, could it be that I'm not setting the x, y axis itself?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

I read the array using this function:

```
def split_at_empty_lines(filename):

with open(filename) as f:
    arr = [] 
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip() and arr:
            yield arr 
            arr = []
        elif line.strip(): arr.extend(float(x) for x in line.split())
    if arr: yield arr;
```

The spectrogram is produced by doing the following:

```
a = list(split_at_empty_lines("file.txt"); 

hm = ax.imshow(a, interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',aspect='auto')
```

Here is the result:

```
[[ 26.9287  30.9089  34.9285 ...,  23.016   28.9027  36.4073]
 [ 26.7964  26.8524  32.7296 ...,  22.9524  28.6145  33.7204]
 [ 26.4222  27.0941  29.094  ...,  22.5309  27.6803  26.7073]
..., 
[ 25.9362  25.8307  29.7039 ...,  22.0084  25.9855  28.9602]
[ 26.4222  27.0941  29.094  ...,  22.5309  27.6803  26.7073]
[ 26.7964  26.8524  32.7296 ...,  22.9524  28.6145  33.7204]]
```

Here is the results:

[image]

I don't know why I'm getting such different results.

Comment: It looks like your problem is more than just transposition. Note that the y-axis of your matplotlib plot goes from 656 to 4594, which does not match the x-axis of your first plot. Do you know the actual dimensions of the array?

Comment: @Bogatron - Hello, I have these values.. I just did not include them in this example

Comment: Have you looked at the first line of the text file to see if the values are the same as the first row of `a`? And are you sure that your C++ file is writing the data in row-major order, rather than column-major?

Comment: @bogatron - hello I've not thought about this because reading in a 1D array from text file generated in C++ it works fine.. Mhm I'm going to take a look. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading the data with [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) into an `ndarray` you can transpose the array before plotting.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(split_at_empty_lines("file.txt"))
print(a.T)
```

should produce

```
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Comment: So the problem, could be how I'm reading in the data in? I'm not using numpy because of the way the text file is set up

Comment: maybe expand your question to show how the data is being fed to `imshow`? but usually its because the axis needs to be swapped.

Comment: so what happens, when you convert `a` into an array and call `imshow` with `a.T`?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my post with the results.. Does this look right, if so, How do I plot this/

Comment: well, `ax.imshow(a.T, interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',aspect='auto')` should produce the desired result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45309/discussion-between-thengineer-and-user1326876)